# Найти второй пробел в строке с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: java

При вводе сложных ФИО, например, Григорьев-Апполонов Пьер-Нарцисс Иванович оглы в в "Отчество" попадает только "оглы". Как найти второй пробел, а не последний?

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if (input.equals("0")) {
            break;
        }
        if (input.matches("([А-Я][а-я]+(-[А-Я][а-я]+)?\\s){2}[А-Я][а-я]+(\\s[а-я]+)?")) {
            int spaceIndex = input.indexOf(' ');
            int spaceIndex2 = input.lastIndexOf(' ');
            System.out.println("Фамилия: " + (input.substring(0, spaceIndex)));
            System.out.println("Имя: " + (input.substring(spaceIndex + 1, spaceIndex2)));
            System.out.println("Отчество: " + (input.substring(spaceIndex2 + 1)));
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вводимая строка не является ФИО");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
int spaceIndex2 = input.indexOf(' ', spaceIndex + 1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, навсегда запомню.